# MongoError: there are no users authenticated, unable to connect to mongodb server

Tags: node.js, mongodb

my server.js file

```
  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:27017/QUIZ_GAME',(err,client)=>{
if(err){
  return console.log('unable to connect to the MongoDb server');
}
 const db =client.db('QUIZ_GAME');
 console.log('connected to the MongoDb server');
```

in my putty terminal i had done this, to enable auth and iwas successful in doing it

```
 use admin
db.createUser(
{
user: "admin",
pwd: "password",
roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
 }
);
exit;

 use QUIZ_GAME
 db.createUser(
{
  user: "tester",
  pwd: "password",
  roles: [{ role: 'readWrite', db:'QUIZ_GAME'}]
```

Comment: just use  `mongodb://localhost/QUIZ_GAME` to connect locally

Comment: Just `'mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:27017` and leave the database name off the connection. The javascript driver changed at version 3.x to be like all the other drivers. In all other drivers, that database name "on the connection string" is the one used for "authentication". When you **omit it***, then the driver looks in `admin` to authenticate. And that is where you *should **always*** be storing the users you create.

Comment: Just to be clear, your user creation as shown in the question is completely correct. It's just where you are pointing the driver to authenticate against where the problem is.

Comment: sorry@NeilLunn i didnt get u

Comment: `MongoClient.connect('mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:27017',(err,client)=>{`. Everything else is okay and that is the only thing wrong.

Comment: that didnt solve my problem. .when i use npm start in my putty , i get the same error

Comment: `MongoClient.connect('mongodb://tester:password@127.0.0.1:27017',(err,client)=>{`. Since you actually told us what the user and password are, then simply copy the code from me, Don't change anything, just use what I typed here on that line. I've supplied the user and password, so you should not need to change that and there is **NO DATABASE** on the end. And that's actually the whole point.

Comment: That was an example of the password. Btw my password contains @as well like abc@ is my password. is this making the difference?

Comment: And btw i am getting the same error even after removing the database name as u mentioned

Comment: having the same error please help on this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806349/node-js-mongodb-connection-error-mongodb-errormongoerror-there-are-no-users

Answer (score 0):

Add your data bearing nodes

```
rs.initiate( {
   _id : "anyId" ,
   members: [ { _id : 0, host : "IP:PORT" } ]
})
```

In future if you want to add any other member then add `rs.add("ip:port")` and then try [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/)

Comment: The rs.initiate() method provides a wrapper around the replSetInitiate command. repl stands for replica

Answer (score -1):

To connect to the server just use

```
db: 'mongodb://username:password@10.2.1.00/db_name'
```

Comment: i know this. .i am uploading my app on the server so i do need to authenticate it