# Error : UTF8 is not a function ,after adding a username and password to mongodb connection string

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have created one sample application for connection of mongodb and nodejs. I got error like 
MongoError: there are no users authenticated

after that I have added username and password to the mongodb connection string like "mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017/marankings"

so authentication eror has gone and it gives me new error like

Buffer.from('n=', 'utf8'),
             ^

TypeError: utf8 is not a function
    at Function.from (native)
    at Function.from (native)

Please guide me on this , I am stuck here.

This is my code

```
connectToServer: function(callback) {
  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017/marankings", function(err, db) {
    //db = db;
    var dbcon=db.db("marankings");
    console.log("this is connected db"+_db);
    var myobj = { name: "Akshay Champavat", address: "akshay@gmail.com" };

    dbcon.collection("users").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 document inserted");
      dbcon.close();
    });

    return callback(err);
  });
},
```

Please help , Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: You may be calling `callback` too early. Have you try puting it in the `insertOne` callback? What does the db look like, is your user really inserted? Also please show us how you retrieve your user.

Comment: @Iso :hey thanks for reaching out me  

User is not inserted ,only I got db connection successfully .
after that it wont allow me to insert user in users collection.@Iso

Comment: Put the password and  the username in the connection url... Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590080/unhandled-promise-rejection-error-url-malformed-cannot-be-parsed/50590439#50590439

Comment: @Anthony :I am not using mongoose here,I am using pure mongoclient here,can you suggest me on that basis.?

Comment: whether it is mongodb or mongoose if you have put username and the password to the database you have to authenticate it... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124255/how-to-connect-with-username-password-to-mongodb-using-native-node-js-driver

Comment: @Anthony : ok , I did it but it gives error like :
express-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/scram.js:189
      Buffer.from('n=', 'utf8'),
             ^

TypeError: utf8 is not a function
    at Function.from (native)
    at Function.from (native)
    at executeScram (/var/www/html/nodejs/express-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/scram.js:189:14)
    at /var/www/html/nodejs/express-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/scram.js:361:7
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)

Comment: please edit your question instead of commenting

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet:Please check now .

Comment: what is your node version and  mongodb version?

Comment: @Anthony : node 4.2.6 and mongodb

mongodb 3.6.4 

db version v3.6.4
git version: d0181a711f7e7f39e60b5aeb1dc7097bf6ae5856
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1604
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64

Comment: Well update your node version if you can otherwise you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260671/typeerror-base64-is-not-a-function-when-using-buffer-from-in-node-4-3

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet : thanks champ !  its resolved , upgrading node version works for me .